# TCP client not handling broken server connect correctly in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I created my own ftp server/client (a very simple version) using TCP. There are 5 possible commands: ls-remote, ls-local, get , put  and exit. Also, I am using multiprocessing in my server code, to be able to handle multiple clients simultaneously by using fork(). Everything is working perfectly except for one thing that I am noticing: I am having a problem handling broken server connect correctly. For example, if something were to go wrong while the server sends a message, I check if the return value from the send call is less than 0, and then I close the socket, and call exit(-1) to terminate the process; however, this causes my client to hang...

my client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void readDirectory();

void syserr(char* msg) 
{ perror(msg); 
  exit(-1); 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int sockfd, portno, n;
  struct hostent* server;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  char buffer[256], temp[256];

  if(argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <hostname> <port>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  }

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);


  server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
  if(!server) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: no such host: %s\n", argv[1]);
    return 2;
  }

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if(sockfd < 0) syserr("can't open socket");

  memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*)server->h_addr);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    syserr("can't connect to server");

  printf("Connection to %s:%s established. Now awaiting commands...\n\n\n", argv[1], argv[2]);


  do{
     printf("%s:%s> ", argv[1], argv[2]); //prompt user for command
     fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
     n = strlen(buffer);

    if(n>0 && buffer[n-1] == '\n')
      buffer[n-1] = '\0';


    if(strcmp(buffer, "ls-remote") == 0){ //display files from server directory
      uint32_t size;
      uint32_t commandSize = strlen(buffer);

       //convert to network form
       commandSize = htonl(commandSize);

       n = send(sockfd, &commandSize, sizeof(commandSize), 0); // send size of command to server 
       if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");

       n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); // send command to server 
       if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");

       n = recv(sockfd, &size, sizeof(size), 0); // recieve the size of the directory
       if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from server");

       size = ntohl(size);
       int currentSize = 0;
       printf("Files at the server: %s\n", argv[1]);

        while(currentSize < size){
            memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
            n = recv(sockfd, buffer, 255, 0); // recieve directory from server 
            if(n < 0) syserr("can't recieve server");

            currentSize = currentSize + n;

            printf("%s", buffer);
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp(buffer, "ls-local") == 0){ //display files from local directory
        printf("Files at the client: \n");
       readDirectory();
    }
    else if(strncmp(buffer, "get ", 4) == 0){ //downlaod file from server


       if(strlen(buffer) < 5){ // no file was entered
          printf("%s\n", "ERROR...missing filename: get <filename>");
        }
       else{
          uint32_t fileSize;
          uint32_t commandSize = strlen(buffer);


          //convert to network form
          commandSize = htonl(commandSize);

          n = send(sockfd, &commandSize, sizeof(commandSize), 0); // send size of command to server
          if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");

          n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); // send command to server
          if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");

           n = recv(sockfd, &fileSize, sizeof(fileSize), 0); // get size of file 
                  if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from server");

          fileSize = ntohl(fileSize);

          if(fileSize == -1){
              printf("%s\n", "File does not exist");
           }
           else{   // file exists
               int totalBytes = 0;
               int bytesWritten = 0;

                // get file name
                char *fileName = strtok(buffer, " ");
                fileName = strtok(NULL, " ");

                memcpy(temp, fileName, strlen(fileName)); //copy filename into temp
                temp[strlen(fileName)] = '\0';


              //create new file with given name
              FILE *fpNew = fopen(fileName, "w");

              if(fpNew){

                  while(totalBytes < fileSize){
                      //receieve the bytes
                      n = recv(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                      if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from server");

                      //write the bytes
                      int b = fwrite(buffer, 1, n, fpNew);

                      if (b < 0)
                      syserr("error writing file");

                      if(n == 0){ // error reading on server side 
                        break;
                      }

                      totalBytes = n + totalBytes;
                      bytesWritten = b + bytesWritten;

                    }

                    fclose(fpNew);
                     if(bytesWritten == fileSize) // all bytes read/written to file successfully
                       printf("Retrieval of file %s: successful.\n", temp);
                     else
                       printf("Retrieval of file %s: unsuccessful.\n", temp);

                 }
                 else{
                       syserr("couldnt open file for writing.");
                 }
           }
        }
     }
     else if(strncmp(buffer, "put ", 4) == 0){ // upload file to server
          if(strlen(buffer) < 5){
          printf("%s\n", "ERROR...missing filename: get <filename>");
        }
        else{
            uint32_t commandSize = strlen(buffer);
            uint32_t  status;

            memcpy(temp, buffer, strlen(buffer)); //copy buffer into temp
            temp[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';

            // get name of file
            char *fileName = strtok(temp, " ");
            fileName = strtok(NULL, " ");
            int bytes;

            FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r"); // open the file

            if(fp){  // file exists and opened
                int totalBytes = 0;
                  //convert to network form
                commandSize = htonl(commandSize);

                n = send(sockfd, &commandSize, sizeof(commandSize), 0); // send size of command to server
                if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");

                n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); // send command to server
                if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");

                // get file size
                fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
                int fileSize = ftell(fp);

               // send the file size
               uint32_t size = htonl(fileSize);

               n = send(sockfd, &size, sizeof(size), 0);
               if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");

               //go back to beginning of file
               fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

               while(totalBytes < fileSize){  // while there are more bytes...

                  bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp); // read bytes fromt he file

                  if(bytes < 0){
                    syserr("Error reading the file.");
                  }

                  totalBytes = totalBytes + bytes;

                   //send the bytes
                   n = send(sockfd, buffer, bytes, 0);
                   if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");


                  if(bytes == 0){ //error reading
                   break;
                  }

                }

               fclose(fp);

               //recieve the final status
                n = recv(sockfd, &status, sizeof(status), 0);
                  if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from server");

                 status = ntohl(status); 

              if(totalBytes == fileSize && status == 1){ // successful on both ends
               printf("Upload of file %s: successful.\n", fileName);
              }
              else{
                 printf("Upload of file %s: unsuccessful.\n", fileName);
              }

          }
           else{
              printf("%s\n", "File does not exist");
           }
        }
     }else if(strcmp(buffer, "exit") == 0){
      uint32_t commandSize = strlen(buffer);
          //convert to network form
          commandSize = htonl(commandSize);

          n = send(sockfd, &commandSize, sizeof(commandSize), 0); // send size of command to server
          if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");

          n = send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); // send command to server
          if(n < 0) syserr("can't send to server");

     }
     else{
       if(strcmp(buffer, "exit") != 0)
         printf("Error...invalid command.\nValid commands: ls-remote, ls-local, get <filename>, put <filename>, exit\n");
     }
   }while (strcmp(buffer, "exit") != 0);

   printf("Connection to server %s:%s terminated, BYE now!\n", argv[1], argv[2]);
   close(sockfd);
   return 0;
 }

void readDirectory(){
  DIR *d = opendir(".");
  struct dirent *dir;
    if (d)
      {
        while((dir = readdir(d))!= NULL)
        {
          printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
      closedir(d);
    }
    else{
       syserr("Error...could not get files from directory.");
    }
  }
```

my server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void syserr(char *msg){
 perror(msg); exit(-1); 
}
void errorHandling(char *msg, int newsockfd){
 close(newsockfd);
 perror(msg); exit(-1); 
}
uint32_t directorySize();
void handle_client(int newsockfd);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, clt_addr;
  socklen_t addrlen;

  if(argc < 1) { 
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
    return 1;
  } 
  if(argc == 1){
    argv[1] = "5555";
  }

  portno = atoi(argv[1]);

  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
  if(sockfd < 0) syserr("can't open socket"); 

  memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

  if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
    syserr("can't bind");
  printf("bind socket to port %d...\n", portno);

  listen(sockfd, 5); 


for(;;){

  printf("wait on port %d...\n", portno);
  addrlen = sizeof(clt_addr); 
  newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&clt_addr, &addrlen);
  if(newsockfd < 0) syserr("can't accept"); 

   pid_t pid = fork();

   if(pid < 0){
    syserr("Error can't fork");
   }
   else if(pid == 0){ // child process
     close(sockfd);
     handle_client(newsockfd);
     close(newsockfd);
     break;
   }
   else{ // parent
     close(newsockfd);
     continue;
   } 

  }
  return 0;
}

uint32_t directorySize(int newsockfd){
    DIR *d = opendir(".");
    struct dirent *dir;
    uint32_t count = 0;

    if (d)
      {
        while((dir = readdir(d))!= NULL)
        {
         //count++;
            count = strlen(dir->d_name) + count + 1;
        }
      closedir(d);
    }
    else{
       errorHandling("Error...could not get files from directory.", newsockfd);
     }

    return count;
  }
  void handle_client(int newsockfd){

    // receieve command size from client
  uint32_t commandSize;
  int n;
  char buffer[256];

  while(1){
  n = recv(newsockfd, &commandSize, sizeof(commandSize), 0); // receive size of command
  if(n < 0) errorHandling("can't receive from client", newsockfd); 

  commandSize = ntohl(commandSize);

  //recieve command
  n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, commandSize, 0); 
  if(n < 0) errorHandling("can't receive from client", newsockfd); 

  else buffer[n] = '\0';


  if(strcmp(buffer, "ls-remote") == 0){  //display files from server directory

      // get the size of the directory
      uint32_t size = htonl(directorySize(newsockfd));

      n = send(newsockfd, &size, sizeof(size), 0); // send size of directory
      if(n < 0) errorHandling("can't send to client", newsockfd); 


      DIR *d = opendir(".");
      struct dirent *dir;

      if(d){
          while((dir = readdir(d))!= NULL){
              memset(&buffer[0], 0, sizeof(buffer));
             strcpy(buffer, dir->d_name);
             buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\n';

             // send file/folder names
             n = send(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
            if(n < 0) 
              errorHandling("can't receive from client", newsockfd); 

       }

        closedir(d);

    }
    else{
       errorHandling("Error...could not get files from directory.", newsockfd);
    }

}
 else if (strncmp(buffer, "get", 3) == 0){  // if command is get
    char *fileName = strtok(buffer, " "); // "get"
    fileName = strtok(NULL, " "); // the name of the file
    FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(fp){  // if file exists
        int totalBytes = 0;
        int bytes;

        // get the size of the file
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
        int fileSize = ftell(fp);

        // send the file size
         uint32_t size = htonl(fileSize);

         n = send(newsockfd, &size, sizeof(size), 0);
         if(n < 0) errorHandling("can't send to client", newsockfd); 


         //go back to beginning of file
         fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

         while(totalBytes < fileSize){ // while there are more bytes to read...

           // read the bytes into the buffer
           bytes = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), fp);
           if(bytes < 0){
            errorHandling("Eorror reading bytes on server side", newsockfd);
           }

            //send the bytes
            n = send(newsockfd, buffer, bytes, 0);
            if(n < 0) errorHandling("can't send to client", newsockfd); 

            if(bytes == 0) // error reading file; bytes should have been > 0
                break;

            totalBytes = totalBytes + bytes;  
        }

         fclose(fp);
    }
     else{
      // tell client file doesnt exist by sending -1
        uint32_t dne = htonl(-1);
        n = send(newsockfd, &dne, sizeof(dne), 0);
        if(n < 0) errorHandling("can't send to client", newsockfd); 

     }
  }
  else if (strncmp(buffer, "put", 3) == 0){ // upload a file
      int totalBytes = 0;
      int bytesWritten = 0;
      int b = 0;
      uint32_t fileSize, status;

      n = recv(newsockfd, &fileSize, sizeof(fileSize), 0);// receive the size of file 
      if(n < 0) errorHandling("can't receive from client", newsockfd); 

      fileSize = ntohl(fileSize);

       // get file name
       char *fileName = strtok(buffer, " ");
       fileName = strtok(NULL, " ");

       //create new file with given name
        FILE *fpNew = fopen(fileName, "w");

          if(fpNew){
            while(totalBytes < fileSize){
                n = recv(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                  if(n < 0) errorHandling("can't receive from client", newsockfd); 

                 if(n == 0){ //bad file transfer on client side
                    break;
                 }

                 //write the bytes 
                 b = fwrite(buffer, 1, n, fpNew);

                 if(b < n){ // error writing to file
                    break;
                 }
                 totalBytes = totalBytes + n; // bytes recived
                 bytesWritten = bytesWritten + b; //bytes written

             }     

                  fclose(fpNew);

                  if(bytesWritten != fileSize){ // not all bytes written
                    status = htonl(-1); 
                  }
                  else{
                    status = htonl(1);
                  }

                  // send the status
                  n = send(newsockfd, &status, sizeof(status), 0);
                   if(n < 0) errorHandling("can't send client", newsockfd); 
          }
          else{
            errorHandling("could not open file for writing.", newsockfd);
          }

      } 
       else{ // command is exit
            printf("%s\n", "closing connection");
            close(newsockfd); // close the connection
            break;

        }

      }

   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = recv(sockfd, &size, sizeof(size), 0); // recieve the size of the directory
if(n < 0) syserr("can't receive from server");
```

That's not sufficient. If `n == 0` the peer has closed the connection: you must do likewise and exit the read loop, or indeed possibly the entire process in your case.

Comment: so I should always check for n <= 0 and then call syserr?

Comment: No. You should check for -1 and call `syserror()`, and then for 0 and close and exit. 0 isn't an error indication, it is an end of stream status, and calling `perror()` after it isn't valid.

Comment: but even when syserror() is called, my client would still hang if n is -1

Comment: You mean it hangs after calling `perror()`? i.e. in `exit(-1)`? Hard to believe. Impossible, actually.

Comment: yes, it is hanging. I read that exit() returns to the parent process. when I add a break in my parents process (after I close the socket) then it seems to fix the issue..but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: No, `exit()` exits the current process completely, and causes `wait()` and friends in the parent process to return. You should certainly close everything prior to doing so. You'll have to explain your actual symptoms, rather than what you think is happening.

Comment: You should at least know *which* it is. Does `perror()` print anything?

Comment: I'm talking about in my server, if there is an error then the process i was servicing is terminated, but then that client hangs.

Comment: Please clarify what on earth you're talking about. Your client hangs *in what code?* After `perror()` prints what?

Comment: In my server code, when the server experiences a problem (ie when n < 0) such as when its trying to send to a client, my errorHandling() method is called and the server is closed for that process. This is fine; however, THEN my client hangs. The client should be able to know that there was a problem and then also call syserr() and terminate the program for the client. This gets fixed when I check for n = 0, but must I check each time?

Comment: **Of course** you must check each time, in both the server and the client. Surely it is obvious that *any* `recv()` can encounter either an error or end of stream? It seems to me that your client isn't hanging at all: it is looping at end of stream.